# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams AND addRule method not working

Tags: android

I'm new here so be gentle with me :).

Im trying to generate a new TextView every button click and place it BELOW another View in the activity.

my XML:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.HairCutsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_id">
    
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:text="@string/header1_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@id/header1"
        android:text="@string/date_text"
        android:inputType="date"
         />
    
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/add_button_text"
        
        />
    


</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java:

```js
package com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.R.id;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.R.bool;
import android.R.integer;
import android.R.layout;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HairCutsActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    TextView header1;
    EditText editText; // Where you insert your new dates
    Button addButton;
    String hairCutDateString;
    TextView dateText;
    public static ArrayList<TextView> datesUploadedList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    int datesUploadedCounter = 0;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    boolean firstInsertFlag = true; // True - first insert


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hair_cuts);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // Setting the window color to white

        header1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header1);
        header1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(32,178,170));

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() // Click on add button
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFromat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                java.util.Date date;
                try
                {
                    date = simpleDateFromat.parse(editText.getText().toString());
                    hairCutDateString = date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + (date.getDate()) + "/" + (1900 + date.getYear()); // The date string
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dateText = new TextView(HairCutsActivity.this);
                dateText.setText(hairCutDateString);
                dateText.setId(datesUploadedCounter);
                datesUploadedCounter++;

                datesUploadedList.add(dateText);
                if (firstInsertFlag) // First insert
                {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    // Setting the new date below the header
                    layoutParams .addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, header1.getId()); 
                    dateText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    relativeLayout.addView(dateText);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,datesUploadedList.get(datesUploadedCounter - 1).getId());
                    editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    firstInsertFlag = false;
                }
                else 
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hair_cuts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now the thing is the BELOW alignment of the EditText is working (BELOW the new TextView) but the alignment of the new TextView to bew BELOW the header1 TextView is not working.

pictures:

Before the click on the button:

http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=fmigy2wimnkz.png

After the click on the button:

http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=ijyg0ytz4nty.png

Anyone know what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Anyone?     I guess its something easy that I didn't noticed..

Comment: instead of adding a text view like this, have you tried using a Listview of textviews?

Comment: @karthik Thanks for the answer. Actually I never used ListView collection, I will try that. So put that instead of the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,datesUploadedList.get(datesUploadedCounter - 1).getId());
```

to

```
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,datesUploadedList.get(dateText.getId());
```

Also you might want to set some margin.

And you don't need handle first add and others so differently.

Take a global TextView

```
 TextView lastTextView = null;
```

and just use (change margins according to your taste)

```
    onclick(){
    .........

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if(lastTextView == null) {
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, header1.getId());
            }else{
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,lastTextView.getId());
            }
           layoutParams.setMargins(100,100,100,100);
            dateText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            relativeLayout.addView(dateText);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            newLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, dateText.getId());
            newLayoutParams.setMargins(200,200,200,200);
            editText.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
            lastTextView =dateText;
    }
```